# Critical Points of Triangle Function (Boundary and Interior)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine the critical points and state whether they correspond to global max or min.

$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ constraint is $\dfrac{x^2}2+y^2\le 1$

I am confused by this question. I know that this will be a triangle and that we need to find the critical points on the boundary and interior. I also know how to get the value of the interior. What I am confused with is how to get the boundary points and how to solve for them. I am used to the triangle questions where they explicitly give us the vertices but this question confuses me. Any explanation would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is not a triangle; it's an ellipse with semi-axes $\sqrt2$ and $1$. We have $\nabla(f)=(2x,2y)$, which is a critical point (zero) only at $(0,0)$, which is a minimum.

Comment: QUESTION EDITED: How would I do the question without using LAGRANDE

Comment: @OGK I didn't use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: I think I copied the wrong question I have submitted a new question with the proper question in mind.

Comment: @OGK Hey, accept this answer then?

Comment: I have accepted it and posted a new question my apologies.